# Separator control in .net Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework

How to draw an horizontal line in .net Compact Framework 3.5, like the one used in the `Owner Information` in Windows Mobile 6.5, that separates the title and the body?

[image]

Comment: Could you edit this to add a screen shot of what you are talking about? I don't understand.

Comment: @jp2code here is the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do something like that is to override the `Paint` event:

```
private const int HORZ_LINE = 10;

private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black)) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, HORZ_LINE, Width, HORZ_LINE);
  }
}
```